# Google Map's view on webpage

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

I've never done `Google Map` Integration for database driven addresses using `Google Map API`.I have got the code for this functionality,but not getting the expected view on web page.I think,this one is a very simple problem for people who dealt with Google Map API before.

Please be informed,I have researched for hours in google developer site,SO and other blogs.But no success,as I'm not sure which factors are causing this problem.

```
This view is what I am getting,
```

[image]
And,expected view is

[image]

Here is the code

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //Sample code written by August Li
  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
  new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
  var center = null;
  var map = null;
  var currentPopup;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pt,
  icon: icon,
  map: map
  });
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: info,
  maxWidth: 300

  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    if (currentPopup != null) {
      currentPopup.close();
      currentPopup = null;
    }
  popup.open(map, marker);
  currentPopup = popup;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
  map.panTo(center);

  currentPopup = null;
  });
  }
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  //map.panBy(0,30);
   //map.setZoom(15);

  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
  },
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
  }
  });
  <?php
   if(isset($_GET['user_map'])){
     $mapusrx=$_GET['user_map'];

     $query = mysqli_query($connecti,"SELECT * FROM map WHERE user_id='$mapusrx'");
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
         $name=$row['title'];
         $lat=$row['lat'];
         $lon=$row['lon'];
         $desc=$row['address'];
         echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
        }
    }
  ?>
  center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  }
```

**CSS**

```
#map { 
width: 240px; 
height: 700px; 
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Special Thanks to Barryhunter,who fixed the problem @ Google Maps Forum**

Just need to use the following code,after `<?php ?> block`

```
center = bounds.getCenter();
map.setCenter(center);
map.setZoom(15);

Changing setZoom() value will give desired view on the map.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //Sample code written by August Li
  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
  new google.maps.Size(240, 700), new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
  var center = null;
  var map = null;
  var currentPopup;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pt,
  icon: icon,
  map: map
  });
  var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: info,
  maxWidth: 300

  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    if (currentPopup != null) {
      currentPopup.close();
      currentPopup = null;
    }
  popup.open(map, marker);
  currentPopup = popup;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
  map.panTo(center);

  currentPopup = null;
  });
  }
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  //map.panBy(0,30);
   //map.setZoom(15);

  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
  zoom: 4,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
  },
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
  }
  });
  <?php
   if(isset($_GET['user_map'])){
     $mapusrx=$_GET['user_map'];

     $query = mysqli_query($connecti,"SELECT * FROM map WHERE user_id='$mapusrx'");
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
         $name=$row['title'];
         $lat=$row['lat'];
         $lon=$row['lon'];
         $desc=$row['address'];
         echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
        }
    }
  ?>
  center = bounds.getCenter();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  }


**CSS**

#map { 
width: 240px; 
height: 700px; 
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try to reduce the 
Zoom:14 level

Comment: I used zoom 4, 6, 7 and some others.But that's weird that,It didn't work.But I found a jfiddle for one SO question where zoom changing was affecting map.And I change other options too,to see the changes.But I don't know why,nothing is changing